# Python - Can I unpivot a table from an excel file and turn the Data Source into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, unpivot

I have a excel file that has only one sheet, and in this sheet there's a lot of information, including two pivot tables that I need the original data (unpivot) get this data source and turn it into a dataFrame.

Here's an [example](http://www.anp.gov.br/images/DADOS_ESTATISTICOS/Processamento_petroleo/Processamento-de-Petroleo-m3.xls) of the file.

Now, the manually way is to click any cell of the pivot table with the right button, select the "Pivot Table Options".
It will open a pop-up. There, select the second tab, "Totals & Filters", and then mark the two firsts check boxs and then click "ok".

After that, I have to go to the last cell in the pivot table (last row of the last column to the right), click two times the green square. It will open the Data Source.

It's way too manual and I'd like to automatize that with python.

Comment: You can use `pd.unstack` or `pd.melt` to achieve this. Can you post an example for others to work on?

Comment: I have tried that, but didn't work.